# Creating Bootable Ubuntu USB from Mac

Tags: mac

I downloaded the iso file of Ubuntu 11.04 (32 Bit) from Ubuntu download page  and followed the instruction of creating Bootable USB Memory Card. from the same download page (http://www.ubuntu.com/download/ubuntu/download).

But after 9th Step i.e. executing the following command

```
sudo dd if=/path/to/downloaded.img of=/dev/rdiskN bs=1m
```

Mac could not detect the USB Memory Card. I have to format the Memory Card again.

Here is a configuration I am trying
1. Mac OSX 10.6.8
2. Ubuntu 11.04  32 Bit iso installation (I Created dmg file as per steps)

Comment: I have the same problem. When I started my Mac holding the alt ley pressed I could not seen my USB drive. I have done all steps exact like in the tut. What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

The "error" you are getting is actually correct. Mac OS X cannot read the ext* family of file systems - it doesn't have the drivers. So after the `dd`, you can eject the USB and carry on.

Comment: what i understand is the usb stick is bootable but it is not recognized by MAC. If this is right then how can I boot ubuntu from usb stick on MAC

Answer (score 0):

As jrg has said, it will not be readable on a mac without software such as [OSXfuse](http://osxfuse.github.io/). Even then the process of dd creates a usb that is read-only.

Simply reboot your mac holding down the left 'alt' key, and you should see your live usb displayed.